# Is there an Ubuntu Server (or other text-only) LiveCD?

Tags: server, live-cd, ubuntu-minimal

I need to test something on a fresh Server install of Ubuntu. Only up to and including `ubuntu-standard`. I'd rather not do a clean install and I'd rather avoid chroot/lxc containers because I want to fire off some really harmful commands and I don't want there to be any chance of nuking my main install.

Is there a small LiveCD or appliance disk available for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Ubuntu Server appliance images that can be loaded into Virtualbox available from several places:

- http://www.thoughtpolice.co.uk/vmware/
- http://virtualboximages.com/VirtualBox+Ubuntu+Client+VDIs
- http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu-server/

These probably shouldn't be trusted but should be okay for my testing purposes.